# Change the date format in broadleaf

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, simpledateformat, broadleaf-commerce

How will I change the date format in Broadleaf? I know a class named FormatUtils.java which is used everywhere in broadleaf. But when I changed the format, some random year value comes at active start date on the product screen..Eg: 1100, 2319 etc

How to change the date format which is being used everywhere?

TIA

Comment: A piece of code will be very helpful for us.

Comment: Then you probably changed it the wrong way. Show your code so people can help you. See: How to create a [mcve]